# toy languages Multiplying without using *

Tags: recursion, lisp

I'm making a Lisp like Toy Languages these days.
but stuck in problem that making a multiply function using without *.

such as `DEFUN MULT(x y) add(add(x y) add(x y-1))` like this.

i tried using recursive method but it goes into infinite loops
so i decide to just using add method with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition `3 * 4` is either `3 + 3 + 3 + 3` or `4 + 4 + 4`. Your code needs to be recursive. To prevent infinite recursion you must have a base case that is sure to hit at some level. A good one would be if you are multiplying with `1` since then the result would be the other argument:

```
(defun mul (x y)
  (if (= x 1) 
      y
      (+ y (mul (1- x) y))))

(step (mul 3 4))       ; ==
(+ 4 (mul 2 4))        ; ==
(+ 4 (+ 4 (mul 1 4)))  ; ==
(+ 4 (+ 4 4))          ; ==
(+ 4 8)                ; ==
; ==> 12
```

This only works for positive integers. To have it work when `x` is zero or negative is left as an exercise.

*NB! Your supplied code does not look like lisp. My example works in any Common Lisp implementation!*

Comment: thanks for the reply, but in my code, it is not Lisp language, it's "Lisp alike language". i think i should ask the question more specifically. thank you anyway!